# Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a webapp using appscript with new V8 engine..When I append a row to a googlesheet, I get the following exception.

```
Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.
```

The code is as follows:For example,

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetId);

var orderedValues=[UID-004, Timestamp, 34, Male , Mr. , xyz, xyz@.com, 26-Jun-2020, country, Yes, Yes, 1, 2, name, rt, religion , 2343545, place, 57, street, phone, esy, 45365, 675]

ss.appendRow(orderedValues);
```

It was working just fine till yesterday..Not sure what the reason is...

Comment: Well it looks pretty clear the the size of the spreadsheet is an issue.

Comment: That made sense..there were two many columns in one of the sheets..thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in comments, and as the exception message clearly says, you reached the 5 million cell limit.

Posting the official reference for documentation purposes:

> - Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.
> - Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns for spreadsheets imported from Microsoft Excel. The limits are the same for Excel and CSV imports.

Consider splitting the data into several spreadsheets. I don't think you want to be anywhere close to that limit (performance will probably get affected for such huge spreadsheets).

#### Reference:

- [Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603)